# If we restrict the domain of $f$ such that $y=g(x)$ is $F_r$ single-variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

If I take a function $f(x,y)$ that is defined on the entirety of the plane $R^2$ and impose a restriction on it such that we get a new function $F_r(x,y)$ with domain $D=${$(a,a)a∈R$}

How would we describe $F_r$ it only will trace a line in our space along the surface of $F$, in this way for all real numbers $x$, $F(x,x)=F_r(x,x)=g(x)$, however $g$ is a single variable function, is $F_r$ also a single variable function, So if $f_r(x,y)=g(x)$ does $F_r=g$

One one hand the domain $D$ is a subset of $R^2$, however if we know the domain of $F_r$ we only need one value to determine the value of $F_r$ at any given point.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AnneBauval is $F_r$ single variable?

Comment: What is your definition for "being single variable"?

Comment: @AnneBauval what is the definition of the term? Because from both ways it seems like $F_r$ can be considered both, it maps from $R^2$ suggesting it is of two variables, but also only one value needs to be known if we know it's domain.

Answer (score 1):

If $F_r = g$ then they must have the same domain. But the domain of $F_r$ is $D$ and the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$. So they are not equal functions.

But we can say that there's a bijection between $D$ and $\mathbb{R}$, say $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to D$ with

$$ \phi(x) = (x,x) $$
$$ \phi^{-1}((x,x)) = x $$

And then the functions are related by composition: $g = F_r \circ \phi$.

Comment: This function has he strange property that it seems multi-varied as it maps from $R^2$ but also it's value at any point can be written as the application of $F_r$ to another function $d(x)=(x,x)$ i.e $F_r(x,y)=F_r(x,x)$ which suggests $F_r(x,y)=F_r ∘d(x)$, however $F_r$ can still be described as multi varied?

Comment: Both: It's formal definition from the domain $D$ is one of a multiple variable function, but thanks to the rewriting @aschepler suggests it is more conveniently viewed as a one-variable function. Beware: do not use $F_r$ to denote both the function $D\to R$ and the function $R\to R$. They are not formally the same though philosophically they are the same object.

Comment: We can also define a "function of two variables" in the first place as a function whose domain is a set Cartesian product: $f: X \times Y \to Z$ where $f(x,y)$ is just the short form of $f(p)$ where $p=(x,y)$. And so on for more variables. Viewed this way, every multi-variable function really is a one-variable function, just with a certain sort of value in the domain.